# Linux command line web browser

Tags: gratis, linux, web-browser, command-line

I'm looking for a web browser that I can install on my VPS and through an SSH client like [Putty](http://www.putty.org/), I can browse the web through. I would like the browser to meet these requirements,

- Runs on Linux
- Command line interface
- Gratis

Comment: W3m, lynx are the most common options. There are also phantomjs and wget/curl. You don't specify what you mean by CLI, and your answers are TUI-browsers which is another league entirely.

Comment: Great point @DeerHunter, I will edit

Comment: I'd be tempted to DV either the question or the answers, but can't be bothered to care.

Comment: @DeerHunter [DV?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/299336) Why?

Comment: @DeerHunter Well instead, how about a comment on why you would be down voting?

Answer (score 1):

Another one I've used is Lynx. It also meets all my requirements of running on Linux, has a command line interface, and is gratis. It's in active development with changes made just a [few days ago](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#index-v2.8.9dev.8) from the time of this writing.

If you're looking for a browser that has a lot of different options that can be turned on and off, I would recommend this software. It's available on Linux, OS X, and even Windows.

## [Lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/index.html)

> Lynx is a fully-featured World Wide Web (WWW) browser for users on Unix, VMS, and other platforms running cursor-addressable, character-cell terminals or emulators. That includes vt100 terminals, other character-cell displays, and vt100 emulators such as Kermit or Procomm running on PCs or Macs.
>
> [image: Lynx UI]

Comment: Why would one pick lynx over other choices?

Comment: If you're looking for a browser that available on many different platforms including Linux, OS X, and Windows; want a command line browser that is very configurable; and a browser that's still in active development, I would recommend Lynx (as described above)

Comment: I have used both Lynx as well as ELinks, and I prefer Lynx due to it's simplicity. If I needed a full-blown browser in my command-line, I would use ELinks, but since I don't I prefer Lynx.

Answer (score -1):

The one I've heard of is ELinks. It's very simple and easy to use. It meets all my requirements of running on Linux, has a command line interface, and is gratis. It supports [many different platforms](http://elinks.or.cz/about.html) including Linux, OS X, and CygWin.

I would recommend ELinks for day to day use. It supports tabs and a download manager. It also has a history and bookmark system. It also has many options that can be configured.

## [ELinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) - Full-Featured Text WWW Browser

> ELinks is an advanced and well-established feature-rich text mode web
> (HTTP/FTP/..) browser. ELinks can render both frames and tables, is
> highly customizable and can be extended via Lua or Guile scripts. It
> is quite portable and runs on a variety of platforms. Check the [about
> page](http://elinks.or.cz/about.html) for a more complete description.
>
> ELinks is an Open Source project covered by the GNU General Public
> License. It originates from the Links project written by Mikulas
> Patocka.
>
> [image: ELinks UI]

Comment: Why would one pick elinks over other choices?

Comment: @Gilles I have added reasons why to use ELinks, is this what you were looking for in this answer as well as the others??

Comment: No, this is still not telling me why I would pick one over the other. I suggest writing a single answers instead of one per program, and writing your own words rather than copying the project descriptions.

Comment: "I would recommend ELinks for day to day use. It supports tabs and a download manager. It also has a history and bookmark system. It also has many options that can be configured." These are my own words and tell users why you should pick this one over the others. [One recommendation per answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/388/133) is the consensus, if you feel that this is wrong and that there is a beter way to go about this, you should then explain on meta instead of downvoting multiple answers.